# Best practice re-direct portion of internal WP images to S3 bucket

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Working on a WordPress site which for a portion of it's posts (prior years) inside the posts the images are referring to a separate WP site (separate virtual host) old.mysite.com meaning there are links such as: http://old.mysite.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/07/photo763.jpg

What I'd like to do, instead of keeping this separate WP site around - move only those images to an S3 bucket and have the posts pull images from there.

Can I do this using a ReWrite rule in .htaccess? I prefer to not edit the individual DB entries as this doesn't seem like a great option nor a good practice...

Remember - there are still new posts eg. 2015/16 years which I prefer to not change those paths as they can stay inside of the current site/wp-content path. Only want to change for those originating from old.mysite.com.

I'm open to any other suggestions.

Thank you.

Comment: `I prefer to not edit the individual DB entries as this doesn't seem like a great option nor a good practice` Why not? A rewrite can probably help but that still makes you have to maintain an old site and how is that a good practice? Sometimes you have to change your architecture based on the need. If your site got say the size of Instagram you'd have to make these adjustments.

Comment: Hm, maybe I wasn't clear enough on this. There's no old site to maintain :) Only the images which are all old...these have already been placed into an archive S3 bucket. And no changes are being made to old posts. If you say it's best to edit DB entries itself no problem, I'll do it....

Answer (score 0):

Since we didn’t have much time to act on this I wanted to post the solution that we came up with in the end in case other people need this.

As noted, the old.site.com is **not** a site that needs to be maintained *(if it was then we might choose a different option here)*. The existing WordPress site has actual links that point to old.site.com/wp-content/uploads.

### Our Solution

In an effort to get this online quick so that users can see the older posts/images/etc we did the following:

1. Copied the uploads directory from old.site.com and placed that into an S3 bucket named old.site.com
2. Next inside Route53 (or wherever you control your DNS) we created a CNAME for old.site.com with target pointing to s3.amazonaws.com
3. Remember you'll need to make the S3 bucket readable for public access - this can be done by right-clicking bucket-name then 'Make Public' or by setting a policy.

Now when we go to our main site all those images point to the S3 bucket rather than an actual virtual host on the server.

Additionally, because the content (images) are inside the S3 bucket we’re paying very little compared to the same space if it had to be inside the actual EC2 instance.

### Another Solution

**(if maintenance is required)**
If we actually wanted to maintain the images from within WordPress (Media Library) for old.site.com then it might be beneficial to move ALL images over to S3. Or even in case the size of the images (uploads) grew very large like Instagram. In that case as *@Panama Jack* suggested we could modify the actual entries in the DB to point to correct location ie. S3 bucket. 
Just be careful not to damage PHP serialized strings, this is a good tool (https://interconnectit.com/products/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) or there are similar WP plugins that can be used.